# editing auto invoice

Tags: civievent

How do I edit the organization's contact information on an invoice automatically generated when a person signs up for a CiviEvent and chooses to Pay Later (also for event registration confirmation)?  The invoice was created by a developer the organization no longer uses, and the organization's address and phone have changed.  We currently have Joomla 3.3.1 and CiviCRM 4.4.5

Answer (score 2):

If the organization's information in its Civi contact record is correct, then the next place I would look would be in the message templates (Administer > Communications > Message Templates, the templates for receipts are under System Workflow Messages).  You should be able to locate the information in those with a find - if you are not familiar with Smarty, however, be careful not to modify the code around the information as you might inadvertently break the template.  (It's probably a good idea to save the version currently in use before you start modifying, just in case you need to step back.)

Hope this helps,
Lesley

Comment: Message templates did the trick!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Lesley said, you may want to consider updating CiviCRM to Version 4.6.x as it has a nice built-in invoice feature.

As it is a customization (and prpobably no one knows how it works in detail?), if you cannot find the template under workflow messages it may be a good idea to upgrade instead of trying to fix the custom function.